# Splitting strings with dates of similar cells

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have a dataframe which contains a date column. But the date column is written as second quarter of 2017.
I want to change this to 4-1-2017. The problem is the string of the date isn't structured the same for each cell.
so what i use now is:

```
data = [{'date' : '2e kw 2017'},{'date' : '3ekw 2017'},{'date' : '4e kw 2017'} ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns =['date']) 

df[['kwartaal','jaar']] = df.date.str.split(" kw ",expand=True) 

df['kwartaal'] = df['kwartaal'].replace(['2e'],'4-1-')
df['kwartaal'] = df['kwartaal'].replace(['3e'],'7-1-')
df['kwartaal'] = df['kwartaal'].replace(['4e'],'10-1-')

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['kwartaal'] + df['jaar'])
```

which gives me the desired result for the second and fourth quarter, but not for the third. What is the best way to split this?

```
        date   kwartaal  jaar
0 2017-04-01       4-1-  2017
1        NaT  3ekw 2017  None
2 2017-10-01      10-1-  2017
```

Comment: Try `df[['kwartaal','jaar']] = df.date.str.split("\s*kw\s*",expand=True)` instead of forcing the spaces before and after `kw`.

Comment: what about using regex: `(\d+[e])` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try replaceing the whole `ekw` groups with `Q` and let Pandas handle the conversion:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].str.replace('e\s*kw\s*','Q'))
```

Output:

```
        date
0 2017-04-01
1 2017-07-01
2 2017-10-01
```

Comment: This looks good. A better one liner solution.

Comment: Yes works great, can u elaborate more on it? `('e\s*kw\s*','Q'))` part isn't really clear to me haha

Comment: @MartijnvanAmsterdam see an explanation [here](https://regex101.com/r/j4Pqgb/1).